# WIFI Is seen but does not connect after install of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros

I just did a clean install of Ubuntu on a new hard drive on my Acer Aspire 15 and it sees all the wifi hot spots around but after selecting mine it gives an error: Connection failed, activation of network connection failed.Password is correct, time and date are correct, I can't find another post with this problem most say they aren't seeing hot spots. In the past with windows I have trouble with the driver and had to download and try a few different ones for the Atheros wifi adapter. I don't know how to change drivers in Linux.

sudo lshw -class network gives:

```
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0504000-b0504fff memory:b0500000-b0503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:ee:65:49:0b:54
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:b0400000-b047ffff memory:b0480000-b048ffff
jeff@jeff-Aspire-E5-571:
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Here are warning msgs from journal:

```
06:27:09 jeff-Aspire-E5-571 NetworkManager[662]: <warn>  [1644665229.8698] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
```

```
06:27:11 jeff-Aspire-E5-571 NetworkManager[662]: <warn>  [1644665231.0118] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
```

```
 06:27:11 jeff-Aspire-E5-571 NetworkManager[662]: <warn>  [1644665231.4697] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: There is no such version as Ubuntu 20 what is the actual version?

Comment: It's version 20.04.3 LST